# Is it possible to find the voltage Vx using mesh analysis? if yes, how?

Tags: circuit-analysis

[image]Good day! Is it possible to find the voltage Vx from this network using mesh analysis? any help is greatly appreciated! below is a picture of my work. thank you!

Data:

I1 = 5A
I2 = 3A
I3 = 1/3A

Comment: Will a yes/no answer suffice really? If no, you should ask a different question.

Comment: sorry, i think i should edit the question :)

Comment: sir @EugeneSh. is it possible? if yes, then how? thanks

Comment: BTW, the picture is not readable.

Comment: Of course it is possible. You have two currents flow through the 9ohm resistor. The total current is their sum (mind the direction). I hope you know how to find a voltage given the resistor and the current..

Comment: @EugeneSh. sir, is the sum or the difference of the two currents? i'm really confused. yeah, i know ohms law, sir. :)

Comment: Difference is the sum with negative sign. This is why I mentioned the directions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Ohm's law.

Since 9Ohm and 72Ohm resistors are in parallel, the voltage across their terminals has to be equal. And since I3 flows trough the 72Ohm resistor (and no other current), you can calculate the voltage across its terminals using Ohm's law.

```
U=I*R. U=1/3A*72Ohm=24V
```

Or, you can calculate the net current flowing trough the 9Ohm resistor. Because I2 and I3 flow in opposite directions, the net current will be their difference.

```
Ir=I2-I3=3A-1/3A=8/3A
Ur=8/3A*9Ohm=24V
```

The answers from both methods match, which is good.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, assuming you've found all the current values correctly, it's possible to find the voltage drop across the various resistors in the circuit.  Vx is the voltage drop across the one resistor, we'll call it Rx.  Think back to Ohm's Law:
$$V_x = I_xR_x$$

where Ix is the current through the resistor.

You've already solved for the various currents in the circuit, so it's just a matter of using them to find Ix:
$$I_x = I_2 - I_3$$